# How to list all the channels in .mdf4 file using asammdf in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asammdf

How to get a list of all the channel names in a .mdf4 file while using asammdf? I read the description [here](https://asammdf.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.2/mdf4.html) but am unable to figure out the exact code.

Comment: Are you on purpose not reading the [most recent](https://asammdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) version of the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://asammdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#mdf4:

> The *groups* attribute is a list of dicts, each one with the following keys:
>
> - […]
> - `channels` - list of Channel objects with the same order as found in the mdf file

And according to https://asammdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/v4blocks.html#channel-class a Channel object has attributes

> - `display_name` - str : channel display name; this is extracted from the XML channel comment
> - `name` - str : channel name

So you should be able to use:

```
mdf4 = MDF4(name_of_mdf4_file)

all_channels = []
for group in mdf4.groups:
    for channel in group['channels']:
        all_channels.append(channel.display_name)
```

Or use `.name` instead of `.display_name`, depending on what exactly you need.